# how to force asp to obtain new key for ticket with method StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)

Tags: asp.net-core

public async Task StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
I wish ASP to call above method to obtain new ticket key for logged in user.

How to force asp to get new ticket !KEY! from our ticket store for logging in?

Comment: Please adding more details about your issue, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs

Comment: in this github link is how cookie with ticket key is created. how to clear _sessionKey in method  HandleSignInAsync so that on login I get new ticket key stored in cookie?

Comment: `CookieAuthenticationHandler` doesn't provide a method which allows us to remote the sessionkey directly, so I'm afraid we don't have a normal way to implement your requirement.